# How to add append text (_lab) to all instances of the same text (system_user) in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am still new to SQL and SQL Developer. Is there a query that can append _lab to all tables and keys containing system_user? I need _lab to append to system_user so it appears system_user_lab. I also need _lab to append to system_user_id like this: system_user_lab_id. Any help would be appreciated, this would save me a lot of time

I am using Fedora and a preconfigured SQL database with tables. I use SQL Developer, but I can use terminal. I need to manipulate the existing SQL tables by appending "_lab" without needing to add the text manually for every "system_user" which would take a very long time.

I am trying to modify the file so that when I run the script, it calls sytem_user_lab, and not system_user.

```
INSERT INTO system_user
( system_user_id

, system_user_name

, system_user_group_id

, system_user_type

, created_by

, creation_date

, last_updated_by

, last_update_date)
```

I only need to append _lab for system_user, system_user_id, and fk_system_user_#. As my .sql document is over 1000 lines, it would take a long time to edit all instances of system_user, and append _lab manually. I am not sure which SQL Query commands I should use.

Comment: I think you want to change the column names -- if this is the case use the alter table command.

Comment: So I would use the query command: ALTER TABLE table_name
MODIFY COLUMN column_name datatype. Would this be ALTER TABLE system_user    MODIFY COLUMN system_user system_user_lab?

Comment: Looks like you want to [`alter table x rename column y to z`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/admin/managing-tables.html#GUID-D8835B01-E36C-4C41-A2C8-BA923D294C37), or possibly just [`rename x to y`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/RENAME.html) if you are talking about renaming tables. Perhaps your question could make that clearer.

Answer (score 0):

> As my .sql document is over 1000 lines, it would take a long time to edit all instances of system_user, and append _lab manually.

Ever heard of search/replace editor capability? I suggest you use it.

- open that file in any editor (Notepad would do)
- "Ctrl + H" opens *replace* option
- enter `system_user` into the "find what" field
- enter `system_user_lab` into "replace with"
- push the "Replace all" button

Then recreate everything in the schema.

Comment: Thank you, this answered my question. Sorry if my question was a little unclear, the search and replace option was what I was looking for.